# html5 audio only loading after refresh with ratchet, push.js

Tags: javascript, html, audio, ratchet-bootstrap, push.js

I'm clicking through to a page that has html5 audio on a mobile site that uses Ratchet.js ( and push.js ) but the html5 audio elements only load if I do a full page refresh or if I use `data-ignore="push"` on the link.

Why is this and how can I make it work without using `data-ignore="push"` ?